# how to deploy a MERN app on aws with different versions

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, version, production-environment, mern

I was wondering how would i deploy different versions of my MERN app on aws.

For example lets say I have an initial deploy and want to deploy an updated version but still have access to the previous deployed version how would i do it?

I can deploy on AWS but want multiple versions of my deployed app incase there is an error in one version of my deployed app

Comment: Deploy where? Can you provide more details, such as deploy to Elastic Beanstalk, EC2 instances in AutoScaling group, ECS ...?

Comment: Aws documentation is the best place to learn that.